# How do I read the output of `dmesg` to determine how much memory a process is using when oom-killer is invoked?

Tags: centos, dmesg, out-of-memory

I asked this question:

[Running `sudo /sbin/service mysqld start` causes system to crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103775/running-sudo-sbin-service-mysqld-start-causes-system-to-crash)

In the comments of one of the answers, a very helpful individual is asking for more information regarding how much memory processes were using when `oom-killer` is invoked.

The output of `dmesg` is ~9000 lines, and hundreds of thousands of characters, though.

An example of the output that I see multiple times throughout the output is this:

```
Out of memory: Killed process 21000, UID 48, (httpd).
mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0

Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff802c1b64>] out_of_memory+0x8b/0x203
 [<ffffffff8020fa5d>] __alloc_pages+0x27f/0x308
 [<ffffffff802139dd>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc8/0x1af
 [<ffffffff8021424e>] filemap_nopage+0x14c/0x360
 [<ffffffff80208e9d>] __handle_mm_fault+0x444/0x144f
 [<ffffffff8020622a>] hypercall_page+0x22a/0x1000
 [<ffffffff8020622a>] hypercall_page+0x22a/0x1000
 [<ffffffff80266d94>] do_page_fault+0xf72/0x131b
 [<ffffffff802456a8>] sys_rt_sigreturn+0x327/0x35a
 [<ffffffff8026393d>] _spin_lock_irq+0x9/0x14
 [<ffffffff802296ed>] do_sigaction+0x18c/0x1a1
 [<ffffffff8025f82b>] error_exit+0x0/0x6e

Mem-info:
DMA per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 0, batch 1 used:0
cpu 0 cold: high 0, batch 1 used:0
DMA32 per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 186, batch 31 used:30
cpu 0 cold: high 62, batch 15 used:51
Normal per-cpu: empty
HighMem per-cpu: empty
Free pages:        4748kB (0kB HighMem)
Active:114975 inactive:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0 free:1187 slab:4839 mapped-file:541 mapped-anon:114505 pagetables:1332
DMA free:2004kB min:48kB low:60kB high:72kB active:540kB inactive:0kB present:9076kB pages_scanned:5699645 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 489 489 489
DMA32 free:2744kB min:2804kB low:3504kB high:4204kB active:459360kB inactive:0kB present:500960kB pages_scanned:11998796 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Normal free:0kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
HighMem free:0kB min:128kB low:128kB high:128kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
DMA: 1*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2004kB
DMA32: 12*4kB 3*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2744kB
Normal: empty
HighMem: empty
586 pagecache pages
Swap cache: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0, race 0+0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
Free swap:            0kB
131072 pages of RAM
5993 reserved pages
5581 pages shared
0 pages swap cached
klogd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0

Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff802c1b64>] out_of_memory+0x8b/0x203
 [<ffffffff8020fa5d>] __alloc_pages+0x27f/0x308
 [<ffffffff802139dd>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc8/0x1af
 [<ffffffff8021424e>] filemap_nopage+0x14c/0x360
 [<ffffffff80208e9d>] __handle_mm_fault+0x444/0x144f
 [<ffffffff80263929>] _spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x14
 [<ffffffff80263929>] _spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x14
 [<ffffffff80251144>] finish_wait+0x32/0x5d
 [<ffffffff80266d94>] do_page_fault+0xf72/0x131b
 [<ffffffff802ff918>] kmsg_read+0x3a/0x44
 [<ffffffff8025f82b>] error_exit+0x0/0x6e

Mem-info:
DMA per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 0, batch 1 used:0
cpu 0 cold: high 0, batch 1 used:0
DMA32 per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 186, batch 31 used:45
cpu 0 cold: high 62, batch 15 used:51
Normal per-cpu: empty
HighMem per-cpu: empty
Free pages:        4748kB (0kB HighMem)
Active:114975 inactive:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0 free:1187 slab:4824 mapped-file:541 mapped-anon:114505 pagetables:1332
DMA free:2004kB min:48kB low:60kB high:72kB active:540kB inactive:0kB present:9076kB pages_scanned:6531037 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 489 489 489
DMA32 free:2744kB min:2804kB low:3504kB high:4204kB active:459360kB inactive:0kB present:500960kB pages_scanned:36231106 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Normal free:0kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
HighMem free:0kB min:128kB low:128kB high:128kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
DMA: 1*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2004kB
DMA32: 12*4kB 3*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2744kB
Normal: empty
HighMem: empty
586 pagecache pages
Swap cache: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0, race 0+0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
Free swap:            0kB
131072 pages of RAM
5993 reserved pages
5581 pages shared
0 pages swap cached
Out of memory: Killed process 21001, UID 48, (httpd).
sudo invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0

Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff802c1b64>] out_of_memory+0x8b/0x203
 [<ffffffff8020fa5d>] __alloc_pages+0x27f/0x308
 [<ffffffff802139dd>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0xc8/0x1af
 [<ffffffff8021424e>] filemap_nopage+0x14c/0x360
 [<ffffffff80208e9d>] __handle_mm_fault+0x444/0x144f
 [<ffffffff8020622a>] hypercall_page+0x22a/0x1000
 [<ffffffff8020622a>] hypercall_page+0x22a/0x1000
 [<ffffffff80266d94>] do_page_fault+0xf72/0x131b
 [<ffffffff8024901b>] skb_dequeue+0x48/0x50
 [<ffffffff80254146>] unix_release_sock+0x19e/0x1fa
 [<ffffffff80261df5>] thread_return+0x6c/0x113
 [<ffffffff80207116>] kmem_cache_free+0x84/0xd7
 [<ffffffff80207116>] kmem_cache_free+0x84/0xd7
 [<ffffffff8025f82b>] error_exit+0x0/0x6e

Mem-info:
DMA per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 0, batch 1 used:0
cpu 0 cold: high 0, batch 1 used:0
DMA32 per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 186, batch 31 used:165
cpu 0 cold: high 62, batch 15 used:48
Normal per-cpu: empty
HighMem per-cpu: empty
Free pages:        4760kB (0kB HighMem)
Active:114996 inactive:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0 free:1190 slab:4821 mapped-file:541 mapped-anon:114468 pagetables:1225
DMA free:2004kB min:48kB low:60kB high:72kB active:540kB inactive:0kB present:9076kB pages_scanned:7319613 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 489 489 489
DMA32 free:2756kB min:2804kB low:3504kB high:4204kB active:459444kB inactive:0kB present:500960kB pages_scanned:13331345 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Normal free:0kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
HighMem free:0kB min:128kB low:128kB high:128kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
DMA: 1*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2004kB
DMA32: 5*4kB 8*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2756kB
Normal: empty
HighMem: empty
586 pagecache pages
Swap cache: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0, race 0+0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
Free swap:            0kB
131072 pages of RAM
5993 reserved pages
4629 pages shared
```

How do I read this in a way that can help me perform this task:

> In the process list that gets dumped into dmesg at the time of the OOM
>   condition, one of the columns should include how much memory each process is using.
>   ...put that output in your question...

Answer (score 4):

The output you provided is missing the information which contains how much memory each process was using at the time the OOM killer was invoked.

Stealing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199731/understanding-the-linux-oom-killers-logs) over on stackoverflow, a full OOM killer message will look like this:

```
[11686.040460] flasherav invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
[11686.040467] flasherav cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[11686.040472] Pid: 2859, comm: flasherav Not tainted 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu
[11686.040476] Call Trace:
[11686.040488]  [<c10e1c15>] dump_header.isra.7+0x85/0xc0
[11686.040493]  [<c10e1e6c>] oom_kill_process+0x5c/0x80
[11686.040498]  [<c10e225f>] out_of_memory+0xbf/0x1d0
[11686.040503]  [<c10e6123>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x6c3/0x6e0
[11686.040509]  [<c10e78d3>] ? __do_page_cache_readahead+0xe3/0x170
[11686.040514]  [<c10e0fc8>] filemap_fault+0x218/0x390
[11686.040519]  [<c1001c24>] ? __switch_to+0x94/0x1a0
[11686.040525]  [<c10fb5ee>] __do_fault+0x3e/0x4b0
[11686.040530]  [<c1069971>] ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x21/0x80
[11686.040535]  [<c10fec2c>] handle_pte_fault+0xec/0x220
[11686.040540]  [<c10fee68>] handle_mm_fault+0x108/0x210
[11686.040546]  [<c152fa00>] ? vmalloc_fault+0xee/0xee
[11686.040551]  [<c152fb5b>] do_page_fault+0x15b/0x4a0
[11686.040555]  [<c1069a90>] ? update_rmtp+0x80/0x80
[11686.040560]  [<c106a7b6>] ? hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x26/0x30
[11686.040565]  [<c106aeaf>] ? sys_nanosleep+0x4f/0x60
[11686.040569]  [<c152fa00>] ? vmalloc_fault+0xee/0xee
[11686.040574]  [<c152cfcf>] error_code+0x67/0x6c
[11686.040580]  [<c1520000>] ? reserve_backup_gdb.isra.11+0x26d/0x2c0
[11686.040583] Mem-Info:
[11686.040585] DMA per-cpu:
[11686.040588] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[11686.040592] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[11686.040594] Normal per-cpu:
[11686.040597] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   5
[11686.040600] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
[11686.040603] HighMem per-cpu:
[11686.040605] CPU    0: hi:   42, btch:   7 usd:   7
[11686.040608] CPU    1: hi:   42, btch:   7 usd:  22
[11686.040613] active_anon:113150 inactive_anon:113378 isolated_anon:0
[11686.040615]  active_file:86 inactive_file:1964 isolated_file:0
[11686.040616]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
[11686.040618]  free:13274 slab_reclaimable:2239 slab_unreclaimable:2594
[11686.040619]  mapped:1387 shmem:4380 pagetables:1375 bounce:0
[11686.040627] DMA free:4776kB min:784kB low:980kB high:1176kB active_anon:5116kB inactive_anon:5472kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15804kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:80kB slab_unreclaimable:168kB kernel_stack:96kB pagetables:64kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:6 all_unreclaimable? yes
[11686.040634] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 865 1000 1000
[11686.040644] Normal free:48212kB min:44012kB low:55012kB high:66016kB active_anon:383196kB inactive_anon:383704kB active_file:344kB inactive_file:7884kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:885944kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5548kB shmem:17520kB slab_reclaimable:8876kB slab_unreclaimable:10208kB kernel_stack:1960kB pagetables:3976kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:930 all_unreclaimable? yes
[11686.040652] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 1078 1078
[11686.040662] HighMem free:108kB min:132kB low:1844kB high:3560kB active_anon:64288kB inactive_anon:64336kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:138072kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:1460kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:61 all_unreclaimable? yes
[11686.040669] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[11686.040675] DMA: 20*4kB 24*8kB 34*16kB 26*32kB 19*64kB 13*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4784kB
[11686.040690] Normal: 819*4kB 607*8kB 357*16kB 176*32kB 99*64kB 49*128kB 23*256kB 4*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 2*4096kB = 48212kB
[11686.040704] HighMem: 16*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 80kB
[11686.040718] 14680 total pagecache pages
[11686.040721] 8202 pages in swap cache
[11686.040724] Swap cache stats: add 2191074, delete 2182872, find 1247325/1327415
[11686.040727] Free swap  = 0kB
[11686.040729] Total swap = 524284kB
[11686.043240] 262100 pages RAM
[11686.043244] 34790 pages HighMem
[11686.043246] 5610 pages reserved
[11686.043248] 2335 pages shared
[11686.043250] 240875 pages non-shared
[11686.043253] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[11686.043266] [ 1084]     0  1084      662        1   0       0             0 upstart-udev-br
[11686.043271] [ 1094]     0  1094      743       79   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[11686.043276] [ 1104]   101  1104     7232       42   0       0             0 rsyslogd
[11686.043281] [ 1149]   103  1149     1066      188   1       0             0 dbus-daemon
[11686.043286] [ 1165]     0  1165     1716       66   0       0             0 modem-manager
[11686.043291] [ 1220]   106  1220      861       42   0       0             0 avahi-daemon
[11686.043296] [ 1221]   106  1221      829        0   1       0             0 avahi-daemon
[11686.043301] [ 1255]     0  1255     6880      117   0       0             0 NetworkManager
[11686.043306] [ 1308]     0  1308     5988      144   0       0             0 polkitd
[11686.043311] [ 1334]     0  1334      723       85   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[11686.043316] [ 1335]     0  1335      730      108   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[11686.043320] [ 1375]     0  1375      663       37   0       0             0 upstart-socket-
[11686.043325] [ 1464]     0  1464     1333      120   1       0             0 login
[11686.043330] [ 1467]     0  1467     1333      135   1       0             0 login
[11686.043335] [ 1486]     0  1486     1333      135   1       0             0 login
[11686.043339] [ 1487]     0  1487     1333      136   1       0             0 login
[11686.043344] [ 1493]     0  1493     1333      134   1       0             0 login
[11686.043349] [ 1528]     0  1528      496       45   0       0             0 acpid
[11686.043354] [ 1529]     0  1529      607       46   1       0             0 cron
[11686.043359] [ 1549]     0  1549    10660      100   0       0             0 lightdm
[11686.043363] [ 1550]     0  1550      570       28   0       0             0 atd
[11686.043368] [ 1584]     0  1584      855       35   0       0             0 irqbalance
[11686.043373] [ 1703]     0  1703    17939     9653   0       0             0 Xorg
[11686.043378] [ 1874]     0  1874     7013      174   0       0             0 console-kit-dae
[11686.043382] [ 1958]     0  1958     1124       52   1       0             0 bluetoothd
[11686.043388] [ 2048]   999  2048     2435      641   1       0             0 bash
[11686.043392] [ 2049]   999  2049     2435      595   0       0             0 bash
[11686.043397] [ 2050]   999  2050     2435      587   1       0             0 bash
[11686.043402] [ 2051]   999  2051     2435      634   1       0             0 bash
[11686.043406] [ 2054]   999  2054     2435      569   0       0             0 bash
[11686.043411] [ 2155]     0  2155     1333      128   0       0             0 login
[11686.043416] [ 2222]     0  2222      684       67   1       0             0 dhclient
[11686.043420] [ 2240]   999  2240     2435      415   0       0             0 bash
[11686.043425] [ 2244]     0  2244     3631       58   0       0             0 accounts-daemon
[11686.043430] [ 2258]   999  2258    11683      277   0       0             0 gnome-session
[11686.043435] [ 2407]   999  2407      964       24   0       0             0 ssh-agent
[11686.043440] [ 2410]   999  2410      937       53   0       0             0 dbus-launch
[11686.043444] [ 2411]   999  2411     1319      300   1       0             0 dbus-daemon
[11686.043449] [ 2413]   999  2413     2287       88   0       0             0 gvfsd
[11686.043454] [ 2418]   999  2418     7867      123   1       0             0 gvfs-fuse-daemo
[11686.043459] [ 2427]   999  2427    32720      804   0       0             0 gnome-settings-
[11686.043463] [ 2437]   999  2437    10750      124   0       0             0 gnome-keyring-d
[11686.043468] [ 2442]   999  2442     2321      244   1       0             0 gconfd-2
[11686.043473] [ 2447]     0  2447     6490      156   0       0             0 upowerd
[11686.043478] [ 2467]   999  2467     7590       87   0       0             0 dconf-service
[11686.043482] [ 2529]   999  2529    11807      211   0       0             0 gsd-printer
[11686.043487] [ 2531]   999  2531    12162      587   0       0             0 metacity
[11686.043492] [ 2535]   999  2535    19175      960   0       0             0 unity-2d-panel
[11686.043496] [ 2536]   999  2536    19408     1012   0       0             0 unity-2d-launch
[11686.043502] [ 2539]   999  2539    16154     1120   1       0             0 nautilus
[11686.043506] [ 2540]   999  2540    17888      534   0       0             0 nm-applet
[11686.043511] [ 2541]   999  2541     7005      253   0       0             0 polkit-gnome-au
[11686.043516] [ 2544]   999  2544     8930      430   0       0             0 bamfdaemon
[11686.043521] [ 2545]   999  2545    11217      442   1       0             0 bluetooth-apple
[11686.043525] [ 2547]   999  2547      510       16   0       0             0 sh
[11686.043530] [ 2548]   999  2548    11205      301   1       0             0 gnome-fallback-
[11686.043535] [ 2565]   999  2565     6614      179   1       0             0 gvfs-gdu-volume
[11686.043539] [ 2567]     0  2567     5812      164   1       0             0 udisks-daemon
[11686.043544] [ 2571]     0  2571     1580       69   0       0             0 udisks-daemon
[11686.043549] [ 2579]   999  2579    16354     1035   0       0             0 unity-panel-ser
[11686.043554] [ 2602]     0  2602     1188       47   0       0             0 sudo
[11686.043559] [ 2603]     0  2603   374634   181503   0       0             0 flasherav
[11686.043564] [ 2607]   999  2607    12673      189   0       0             0 indicator-appli
[11686.043569] [ 2609]   999  2609    19313      311   1       0             0 indicator-datet
[11686.043573] [ 2611]   999  2611    15738      225   0       0             0 indicator-messa
[11686.043578] [ 2615]   999  2615    17433      237   1       0             0 indicator-sessi
[11686.043583] [ 2627]   999  2627     2393      132   0       0             0 gvfsd-trash
[11686.043588] [ 2640]   999  2640     1933       85   0       0             0 geoclue-master
[11686.043592] [ 2650]     0  2650     2498     1136   1       0             0 mount.ntfs
[11686.043598] [ 2657]   999  2657     6624      128   1       0             0 telepathy-indic
[11686.043602] [ 2659]   999  2659     2246      112   0       0             0 mission-control
[11686.043607] [ 2662]   999  2662     5431      346   1       0             0 gdu-notificatio
[11686.043612] [ 2664]     0  2664     3716     2392   0       0             0 mount.ntfs
[11686.043617] [ 2679]   999  2679    12453      197   1       0             0 zeitgeist-datah
[11686.043621] [ 2685]   999  2685     5196     1581   1       0             0 zeitgeist-daemo
[11686.043626] [ 2934]   999  2934    16305      710   0       0             0 gnome-terminal
[11686.043631] [ 2938]   999  2938      553        0   0       0             0 gnome-pty-helpe
[11686.043636] [ 2939]   999  2939     1814      406   0       0             0 bash
[11686.043641] Out of memory: Kill process 2603 (flasherav) score 761 or sacrifice child
[11686.043647] Killed process 2603 (flasherav) total-vm:1498536kB, anon-rss:721784kB, file-rss:4228kB
```

Down at the bottom, starting at the line with printk time `11686.043253`, is the table which contains the required information.

---

If you do not have this table in your output, its possible your `dmesg` command is defaulting to a minimum output level higher than what this information is logged at.
Try the following command instead:

```
dmesg -l info,notice,warn,err,crit,alert,emerg
```

When I dig through the kernel source, I see the process table is logged at the `info` level. The `dmesg` command above says to show everything from `info` to `emerg`.

---

Now that we have the information we need, the table is rather self explanatory. The `rss` column will more or less give you how much memory each process was using at the time. The unit of the value is in pages, which is usually 4kb. So a `2` means `8kb`. The `oom_score_adj` column will tell you how likely the kernel is to kill that process (higher number means more likely).

Comment: Hmmm.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is a `-l` option in my version of dmesg.  Do I need to update this? (I'm hosed, aren't I?)

Comment: Looks like redhat `dmesg` doesn't have `-l`. So with `dmesg` you're stuck yes. However if you have your syslog daemon set to pick up kernel messages, your syslog logs might have it.

Comment: I just took a look through the syslog in "messages", and it looks like it does not have any of those tables of processes.

Now I'm sad.  I think the last thing I have left is either making `sshd` and `mysqld` exempt from `oom-killer`, or disabling `oom-killer`, which I'm not sure I want to.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment so I'll add this:

I didn't enable swap before because I did not realize that this was a Xen Virtual Machine.  Once I enabled swap, I could actually get MySQL running without everything dying, essentially fixing my issue.  

For some reason, it's using 363mB of memory, so now I need to figure out how to get the person in charge of the VM to increase the RAM available to it, or decrease the amount of memory that MySQL uses.

Thank you Patrick, for all of your help.

Comment: I believe that the memory usage in the task dump is given as number of pages rather than kb.